# Are there ayat in the Quran that show that Allah will punish those who murder another person, whether he is a Muslim or a Non-Muslim?

Tags: quran, reference-request

With the [Memon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yakub_Memon) Case in India, there is a big debate about Capital Punishment of Memon. I am against Capital Punishment for many reasons. One of them is that life is given by God and it is His will to take it back anytime He wants and humans have no right to harm God's creation.

Are there ayat in the Quran that show that Allah will punish those who murder another person, whether he is a Muslim or a Non-Muslim?

Comment: Capital punishment is one of the laws of Islam, which is followed under some conditions e.g. Sunan Abu-Dawud, Prescribed Punishments (Kitab Al-Hudud) Book 38, Number 4339:(first hadith) [here](http://www.usc.edu/org/cmje/religious-texts/hadith/abudawud/038-sat.php)

Answer (score 1):

Below are the two Translated Quranic verses.

> And whoever kills a believer intentionally, his punishment is Hell; he shall abide in it, and Allah will send His wrath on him and curse him and prepare for him a painful chastisement. **(Surah an-Nisā’ 4:93)**

And:

> O you who believe! Al-Qisâs (the Law of Equality in punishment) is prescribed for you in case of murder: the free for the free, the slave for the slave, and the female for the female. But if the killer is forgiven by the brother (or the relatives, etc.) of the killed against blood money, then adhering to it with fairness and payment of the blood money, to the heir should be made in fairness. This is an alleviation and a mercy from your Lord. So after this whoever transgresses the limits (i.e. kills the killer after taking the blood money), he shall have a painful torment. **(Al-Baqarah 2:178)**